# A class for solving a system of linear equations using Gaussian Elimination

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
class LinearEquationSolver
{
    List<LinearEquation> rows = new List<LinearEquation>();
    decimal[] solution;

    public void AddLinearEquation(decimal result, params decimal[] coefficients)
    {
        rows.Add(new LinearEquation(result, coefficients));
    }

    public IList<decimal> Solve()       //Returns a list of coefficients for the variables in the same order they were entered
    {
        solution = new decimal[rows[0].Coefficients.Count()];

        for (int pivotM = 0; pivotM < rows.Count() - 1; pivotM++)
        {
            int pivotN = rows[pivotM].IndexOfFirstNonZero;

            for (int i = pivotN + 1; i < rows.Count(); i++)
            {
                LinearEquation rowToReduce = rows[i];
                decimal pivotFactor = rowToReduce[pivotN] / -rows[pivotM][pivotN];
                rowToReduce.AddCoefficients(rows[pivotM], pivotFactor);
            }
        }

        while (rows.Any(r => r.Result != 0))
        {
            LinearEquation row = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.NonZeroCount == 1);
            if (row == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            int solvedIndex = row.IndexOfFirstNonZero;
            decimal newSolution = row.Result / row[solvedIndex];

            AddToSolution(solvedIndex, newSolution);
        }

        return solution;
    }

    private void AddToSolution(int index, decimal value)
    {
        foreach (LinearEquation row in rows)
        {
            decimal coefficient = row[index];
            row[index] -= coefficient;
            row.Result -= coefficient * value;
        }

        solution[index] = value;
    }

    private class LinearEquation
    {
        public decimal[] Coefficients;
        public decimal Result;

        public LinearEquation(decimal result, params decimal[] coefficients)
        {
            this.Coefficients = coefficients;
            this.Result = result;
        }

        public decimal this[int i]
        {
            get { return Coefficients[i]; }
            set { Coefficients[i] = value; }
        }

        public void AddCoefficients(LinearEquation pivotEquation, decimal factor)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Coefficients.Count(); i++)
            {
                this[i] += pivotEquation[i] * factor;
                if (Math.Abs(this[i]) < 0.000000001M)    //Because sometimes rounding errors mean it's not quite zero, and it needs to be
                {
                    this[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            this.Result += pivotEquation.Result * factor;
        }

        public int IndexOfFirstNonZero
        {
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (this[i] != 0) return i;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int NonZeroCount
        {
            get
            {
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (this[i] != 0) count++;
                }
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any edge-cases I've missed? Is there a better way to handle potential rounding errors than just checking if a value is close to zero and zeroing it if it is? Is it overkill to use Decimals like this?

Here's a test program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinearEquationSolver test = new LinearEquationSolver();

        test.AddLinearEquation(5, 1, 2, 1, -1);
        test.AddLinearEquation(16, 3, 2, 4, 4);
        test.AddLinearEquation(22, 4, 4, 3, 4);
        test.AddLinearEquation(15, 2, 0, 1, 5);
        var result = test.Solve();

        foreach (var asdf in result)
        {
            Console.Write(asdf);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion even when testing you should give variables meaningful names, otherwise you will develop a bad habit which might be hard to overcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `Enumerable.Count()` vs count access

One problem that slows your program's performance is that you call

```
Coefficients.Count()
```

In a few places while you are using array instead of an `IEnumerable<T>` where this is the only way to count the elements and as you can see this is a method rather than being a property. Instead you should simply call `Coefficients.Length`.

**Edit**

As [@t3chb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134000/a-class-for-solving-a-system-of-linear-equations-using-gaussian-elimination/150758?noredirect=1#comment283918_150758) pointed in the comments and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969468/5687778) C# will simply return the `Count` property of the collection even when you call the method `.Count()` which means `Coefficients.Count()` & `Coefficients.Length` are **almost** equivalent in performance since the method has to do a type checking.

Nevertheless when possible, you should always prefer using your collection's specific functions and properties, rather than the generic ones. In your case `Coefficients.Length`.

### Properties vs fields

Ideally you should always use properties instead of fields

> ```
> public decimal[] Coefficients;
> public decimal Result;
> ```

Can become

```
public decimal[] Coefficients { get; }
public decimal Result { get; set; }
```

You properties should be as restrictive as possible the less your class exposes the better.

### Indexer with public backing collection ?

This doesn't makes much sense. Usually when a class has a indexer it's used internally with a private backing collection, but you have an iterator + a public collection.

In your case I don't see any reason why would you use an indexer here the public array `Coefficients` is more than enough and it's a lot more readable, so you should remove that indexer and just access the array like this :

> ```
> public void AddCoefficients(LinearEquation pivotEquation, decimal factor)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < this.Coefficients.Length; i++)
>     {
>         Coefficients[i] += pivotEquation.Coefficients[i]*factor;
>         if (Math.Abs(Coefficients[i]) < 0.000000001M)
>             //Because sometimes rounding errors mean it's not quite zero, and it needs to be
>         {
>             Coefficients[i] = 0;
>         }
>     }
>     this.Result += pivotEquation.Result*factor;
> }
> ```

### Redundant `this` qualifier

While I do agree that this is up to a personal preference I don't like it. You don't need a single `this` qualifier in your code it would be better to remove it it's just extra text to read..

### Expression bodied properties + *LINQ*

> ```
> public int IndexOfFirstNonZero
> {
>     get
>     {
>         for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Length; i++)
>         {
>             if (Coefficients[i] != 0)
>             {
>                 return i;
>             }
>         }
>         return -1;
>     }
> }
>
>
> public int NonZeroCount
> {
>     get
>     {
>         int count = 0;
>         for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Length; i++)
>         {
>             if (Coefficients[i] != 0) count++;
>         }
>         return count;
>     }
> }
> ```

You can really shorten those get only properties using *LINQ* :

```
public int IndexOfFirstNonZero
{
    get
    {
        int value = (int) Coefficients.FirstOrDefault(x => x != 0);
        return value == default(int) ? -1 : value;
    }
}

public int NonZeroCount => Coefficients.Count(t => t != 0);
```

Comment: One correction. The `Count` extension is smart enough to not enumerate a collection if it implements the `ICollection` interface, see [Enumerable.Count<TSource> Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) _If the type of source implements ICollection<T>, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count._

Comment: And a tip: I suggest qouting the OP's code in the answer. This way it's easier to distinquish it from the review ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @t3chb0t I will make sure to apply that to my future answer, I will update the answer with the correction you mentioned.